# Support for Django 1.4 in google-app-engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

When can we expect support for django 1.4 in Google App Engine?

Comment: I think you should ask this in a Google App Engine forum.

Comment: @Paragon [This is the Google App Engine forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-java/8zQtq_m9W5w)

Answer (score 5):

There is an [open issue about django 1.4 update](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7218&q=1.4%20django&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) you should star it and you will get notified on the issue.

Answer (score 4):

As of October 23, 2012, “[Django 1.4 is now fully supported for Python 2.7](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2012/10/app-engine-173-released.html).”

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its released and supported: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7218